Apache Spark - Parse JSON When Column Could Be String or Array
I have a JSON file which can have the following schema defined
root
 |-- exports: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- counter: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- exportType: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

In other instances however the exportType column is a string and not an array.
root
 |-- exports: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- counter: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- exportType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

I create a DF with the following code df = spark.read.option("multiline","true").json(json_file_path) and after which I try to parse out the JSON.
df_flatten = df.withColumn("exports_explode",explode("exports")) \
.withColumn("counter",col("exports_explode.counter")) \
.withColumn("exportType", explode_outer("exports_explode.exportType") )

This all works fine, when the schema is an array, but when it is string it throws
[DATATYPE_MISMATCH.UNEXPECTED_INPUT_TYPE] Cannot resolve "explode(exports_explode.exportType)" due to data type mismatch: Parameter 1 requires the ("ARRAY" or "MAP") type, however "exports_explode.exportType" has the type "STRING".

When the exportType is string, I have added code to change it to array , but this then breaks the use case when exportType is already an array (as I am creating an array within an array).
df_flatten = df.withColumn("exports_explode",explode("exports")) \
.withColumn("counter",col("exports_explode.counter")) \
.withColumn("exportTypeArray", array("exports_explode.exportType") ) \
.withColumn("exportType", explode_outer("exportTypeArray")

How can I handle this so that both use cases work with the same code base?
